# PyCrypto: AES decryption failing, something to do with byte/string conversion?

Tags: python, flask, cryptography, aes, pycrypto

I'm really not sure what the problem is. I've tried encoding the cyphertext in the decrypt() method before actually decrypting it, as well. Instead of displaying the proper plaintext message, it displays a garbled mess of characters different from the original cyphertext.

This is all embedded in a Flask app web API, which is why I need to decode the bytes:

```
 ########CALLING DECRYPT FROM HERE########

 def get(self):
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()

    parser.add_argument('mode', required= True)
    parser.add_argument('key', required= False)
    parser.add_argument('text', required= False)

    args = parser.parse_args()  # parse args to dict
    mode = args['mode']

    if mode == 'keygen':
        return self.keygen()

    elif mode == 'encrypt' and args['key'] != None and args['text'] != None:
        return self.encrypt(args['key'], args['text'])
    
    elif mode == 'decrypt' and args['key'] != None and args['text'] != None:
        return self.decrypt(args['key'], args['text'])

 ###########################################
 def keygen(self):
    key = urandom(16)
    dkey = b16encode(key).decode('utf-8')
    return {'key': dkey}  # return cryptographic key

def encrypt(self, key, raw):
    crypt = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    ciphertext = crypt.encrypt(raw)  # type() yields 'bytes'

    # have to decode, flask wont allow bytes in json
    ciph = b16encode(ciphertext).decode('utf-8')  

    return {'secret': ciph}

def decrypt(self, key, cipher):
    # TODO not decrypting properly
    # have a suspicion that the failed decryption has to do with cipher being a str input
    crypt = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)

    plaintext = crypt.decrypt(cipher)
    raw = b16encode(plaintext).decode('utf-8')

    return {'message': raw}
```

Any help would be appreciated! I'm not sure if I'm making a stupid mistake here.

Comment: The ciphertext must be hex decoded in `decrypt()` _before_ decryption. In principle, you can do this when calling the method (which you didn't post, so it's not clear if this is done). That's why it makes sense to share a _complete_ example. The hex encoding _after_ decryption on the other hand is not necessary (unless the plaintext is binary data to be represented as string). Btw a static IV is insecure.

Comment: I did not hex decode it before calling the method, but I'd rather do it in the method anyway. How would I go about doing this? Do you think, assuming it's properly done, it would fix the problem?

EDIT: Also, the static IV is temporary.

Comment: I also added the calling code to the block for you to see.